# VHDL shift amount based on highest bit set

Tags: vhdl, bit, shift, floor

I have two numbers (1 smaller and 1 bigger number), where i'd like the shift the lower number to match the higher number in 1 clock cycle. This should be doable with something like:

```
shift_amt <= floor(log2( bigger_num )) - floor(log2( smaller_num );
```

example:

```
signal bigger_num : unsigned(7 downto 0) := "00001111"; --15, high bit 3
signal smaller_num : unsigned(7 downto 0) := "00000010"; --2, high bit 1
--shift_amt should = 2
```

The problem:

floor(log2()) doesn't seem to want to take bigger_num or smaller_num as a parameter.

I need to do this calculation dynamically (not constant).

Sorry i'm a newbie at vhdl. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can not compute the logarithm of a signal's value using `log2`. This would require a complex sequential module to calculate such a value. I assume from your incomplete example that you want to normalize 2 numbers for an addition... You just need to get the position/index of the highest bit set. That can be computed without any use of logarithm functions. Moreover, `log2` and `floor` are using REAL values which can't be synthesised.

Comment: This is sometimes called "normalisation". 2 priority encoders : subtract : barrel shifter : done.

Comment: Your code snippets don't comprise a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You're missing a a closing parenthesis on your signal assignment and there is no predefined "log2" that operates on `unsigned` found in the IEEE libraries. You're missing your context clause and the declaration for `shift_amt`, nor are you sharing anything resembling an error message. An mcve could be as simple as - context clause, empty entity, architecture, declare `bigger_num`, `smaller_num`, `shift_amt`, and a concurrent assignment to `shift_amt` (w/added paren).